# Ubuntu - MongoDB service won't start

Tags: mongodb

Trying connect to a dev's environment MongoDB (3.6) ubuntu server fails, after digging around I've found the the MongoDB service crushed and fails to restart, getting the following error:

> (code=exited, status=14)

Digging deeper into the logs the following error appears:

```
Unable to start up mongod due to missing featureCompatibilityVersion document.
Please run with --repair to restore the document.
```

Running `mongod --repair`, seems the process finish successfully, but trying to start the service again still fails with the same error.

Is there a way to fix or get around it?

If not, is there maybe a way to export the data so I can reinstall mongo and import it to the new installation? I don't mind reinstalling mongo from scratch, just don't want to lost all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue with the `mongod --repair` was that the service and the command looked at different `dbpath`.

Specifying the `--dbpath` flag to the `--repair` command fixed the issue :)